# Is there a way to make a field so that there can only be one yes per FK?

Tags: filemaker

I am on Filemaker 18 Pro and new to Filemaker in general. I created a table of Clients and a table of Properties. One client can have multiple properties (ie One to Many relationship). I want to have a flag to indicate that the property is the Client's Primary Address. So basically the field will be:

isPrimary = "Yes" or isPrimary = "No".
There can only be one "Yes" per Client ID
There HAS to be one "Yes" value per Client ID
If you add "Yes" then it will change the existing "Yes" to "No"

Is there a best practice for doing this?

Comment: When any property get updated with IsPrimary = Yes, excute update query like

UPDATE SET IsPrimary = NO where client_Id = "YOUR CLIENT ID" AND WHERE PROPERTYID ! = "RECENTLY EDITED PROPERTY ID"

AND THEN UPDATE The RECENTLY EDITED PROPERTY.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a best practice for doing this?

Yes, there is. If only one property can be the client's primary address, then the identity of the primary address is an attribute of the client, and **should be recorded in a field of the Client's table** - e.g. a Number field storing the selected property's PropertyID.

To "flag" the primary address, use an unstored calculation, or a conditionally formatted object, using the formula:

```
Clients::PrimaryAddressID = PropertyID
```

In this arrangement, selecting a new primary address will automatically remove the flag from the previous address and place it on the newly selected one.

---

P.S.
It is much more convenient to use the values 0 and 1 (or empty and 1) for Boolean fields. The field itself can be formatted to *display* as "Yes" or "No".

Answer (score -1):

You can loop the Properties portal/records and set "No" for other records.